# Show/hide top nav-bar menu item on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

After digging on several SO questions/googling, I've managed to show/hide a menu item depending on if the user is logged on or not.
The site is built on Wordpress, not many plugins.

To accomplish this, my Theme CSS now holds this code

```
.nav-menu  .DtlMenu {
 display:none;
}
.logged-in .DtlMenu {
 display:block;
}
```

DtlMenu is the CSS class assigned to this particular menu item.
Already done a GREP on the WP directory tree, looking for some place where .logged-in is affected, with no luck

Now, this is the question: how can I control this show/hide depending on certain event that happens in my code, and not on the .logged-in 'variable'.
How can I set that control element from PHP code implemented already as a custom plugin.

Any help, or alternative ways  will be appreciated a lot

Thanks and have a great day

Emilio

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on CSS to hide a menu if the user is not logged in (which would still allow a not logged in user to see the menu in the page's source anyways), you can use the [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function in WordPress. Just use this in the appropriate location in your template code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //Menu code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to be able to control this on another condition, not on the fact that the user is logged in or not. The specific condition is if the user has already done some query, and results are available for the page. Cheers

Comment: Well then perhaps update your question with a bit more information. Your question seems pretty vague. We likely don't need to know what it was you were doing before, just exactly what you're trying to do now. @Accuanto

Comment: Ok Myles... what I need is to be able to show/hide certain menu item depending on certain event that has to happen before enabling that menu option. Then, if the user performs another action, to be able to hide it.  Thanks, Emilio

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress nav menu is rendered by the wp_nav_menu() function. Wrap that in your condition.

```
if ( 'whatever_your_condition' == true) {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'your-nav-name',
        'menu_class'     => 'nav'
    ));
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/